# Python3 Syntax for combining dataframe column/rows selections and builtin functions

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, series, selectedindex

how would you combine selected rows of  a dataframe with builtin functions in correct syntax?
The key equation (that has error) is marked with '***' below.  There are three aspects of this equation:
(1) Operation is only on selected rows [lo:hi] and column [ColumnName] of a dataframe
(2) Go through NaN entries in this selection and set each of them to a random number as defined by (3)
(3) The random number is defined by library function np.random.randint with 
(a) range of values between (avg+std) and (avg-std) with a total of size=null_total[ColumnName] entries to be generated.
(b) The random number is then divided by avg to normalize the value. 
avg and std are the mean and standard deviation of all of selected row values  under [ColumnName] as computed by built in dataframe functions  .mean and .std  , respectively. avg,std and null_total are declared to be Dataframe type although they could be just series.

```
def process_Fill_and_Normalize(df,lo,hi,ColumnName):
   avg = pd.DataFrame()
   std = pd.DataFrame()
   null_total = pd.DataFrame()
   avg[ColumnName] = df[ColumnName][lo:hi].mean()
   std[ColumnName] = df[ColumnName][lo:hi].std()
   null_total[ColumnName] = df[ColumnName][lo:hi].isnull().sum()    
   ***df[ColumnName][lo:hi][np.isnan(combined[ColumnName][lo:hi])] = 
   np.random.randint(avg[ColumnName] - std[ColumnName], avg[ColumnName] + 
   std[ColumnName], size=null_total[ColumnName])/avg[ColumnName]
   return df
```

Error message is as follows:

```
   ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, 
   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
  /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in 
  __nonzero__(self)
    915         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
    916                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or 
    a.all()."
    --> 917                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
    918 
    919     __bool__ = __nonzero__
```

You advice on how to modify the syntax would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks to reply from hpaulj that advises to break up the long equation. The index expression is defined in a separate equation.  The following modified code works:

```
def process_Fill_and_Normalize(df,lo,hi,ColumnName):
   avg = pd.DataFrame()
   std = pd.DataFrame()
   avg[ColumnName] = df[ColumnName][lo:hi].mean()
   std[ColumnName] = df[ColumnName][lo:hi].std()
   null_total[ColumnName] = df[ColumnName][lo:hi].isnull().sum()
   mull_entry_index = np.isnan(combined[ColumnName][lo:hi])
   df[ColumnName][lo:hi][mull_entry_index] = 
     np.random.randint(avg[ColumnName] 
     - std[ColumnName], avg[ColumnName] + std[ColumnName], 
     size=null_total[ColumnName])/avg[ColumnName]
   return df
```

Comment: Break up the long expression.  This value error is raised when you use an array or series in simple boolean context.  If the context expects a scalar true/false, but the array has several values.

Comment: hpaulj,  Thank you very much for your advice.  Following your guidance, the code works now.